# How to easily detect that Visual Studio credentials need to be re-entered?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

From time to time when working with an Azure Function, I get pages and pages of errors and I waste a few minutes looking through them until I realize "oh, yeah I need to click on the "re-enter your credentials link" that appears when you click on your initials in the title bar of Visual Studio on the top right.

Is there an easy way to programmatically detect this upfront, specifically, rather than having to wade through pages and pages of error logs to re-figure this out every couple of weeks?

Comment: I suppose you could write a VS Extension that opens the Account Settings page on-startup every 14 days.

Comment: @Dai I was thinking more along the lines of a test specifically for this thing run at application startup. Either way, how do I write the `DoCredentialsNeedToBeEntered()` function. That's the part I am hoping to get some assistance with.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around VS' internals, I think you'll want to do this:

- Create a VSIX project
- Add references to:

  - `Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.Client`
  - `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.Interactive`
  - `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected`
- In your VSIX, use `EnvDTE` to get a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.AccountManagement.IAccountManager` service.
- Use `IAccountManager.GetAccountProviderAsync(Guid)` with GUID `552afc90-145a-469c-8c31-943595db4a66` to get the Azure `IAccountProvider` account provider instance.

  - These GUIDs are listed in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll`'s Manifest Resources named:

    - `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.AccountManager.DefaultWellKknownCloudConfigurations.json`
    - `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.AccountManager.DefaultWellKknownCloudConfigurationsV2.json`
- Iterate over `Account` objects from `azureAccountProvider.AccountStore.GetAllAccounts()`

  - And pass each `Account` into `await azureAccountProvider.RefreshAuthenticationStateAsync(account)`
  - After the `await` completes, check the `account.NeedsReauthentication` property.